# Where is the bunker at Fiddler's Green Trailer Estates?

Tags: fallout-4

[image: fiddlers green]

I have found a radio signal, it says:

> Anyone out there; if you can hear me I'm trapped inside a bunker in... er, what is this? Fiddler's Green Estates. Got some crawlies outside - it's nothing I couldn't normally handle but I'm nursing a bum leg. Could use an assist

However, after killing everything and searching all of the trailers I am still no closer to finding him.

Where is the bunker at Fiddler's Green Trailer Estates?

Comment: Oh, good. I'm not the only one who had problems here. Ended up looking in one of the wikis for it myself. Really disappointing to find - as with practically all radio broadcasts so far - that this was just a leftover beacon. The guy sounded so nice. BTW: I think he said "bum" instead of "boned".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The bunker can be found between two trees in the inner corner of a wooden fence.  I know this description doesn't do it justice, so here's a screencap:

[image]

Comment: Even with the picture that still took me a moment to work out where it was -.- Thanks!

Comment: Was there anybody in there? Or was it just a looping broadcast from a long time ago?

Comment: Possible better image compliments of nukapedia - http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/File:Fiddler's_Green_Bunker_Location.jpg

Comment: @DCShannon Nearly every radio beacon I've tracked down, this one included, was just a leftover automated signal from someone who'd died/left long ago.

Comment: Wow, I wasted so much time trying to find this bunker and it’s totally not worth it. A few caps and some junk. Whoopie!